# Javascript code working in IE but not working in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have this code :

```
<a href="javascript:document.forms['form1'].student_pic.click()">
    <img src="images/mypic.png" alt="" width="161" height="29" border="0" style="margin-top:10px" />
</a>
<input style="display:none" type="file" name="student_pic" id="student_pic" />
```

This code is working successfully in IE but it's not working in FF.

off course there is form on my page called `form1`

When the user click the image, select file window will let the user select image and put it in hidden file element.

What is the proplem?

Thanks

Comment: does is have a form with ID of form1 or a name of form1?

Comment: Can you share the code of student_pic.click()?

Comment: student_pic is the name of file element on my page, what do you mean??

Comment: @Mark Baijens: .click() is a method provided by the browser. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom/element.click

Comment: @idealmachine oops read the . as a _. It's still early :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common way around is have the file input in place but with opacity of 0 which actually means it's hidden, and over it place your custom image or text. Make sure the "browse" button is exactly where your text/image is and it will work - clicking the custom text/image will actually click the browse buttton.

I have such code somewhere so if you won't be able to achieve this I'll search for that code.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is simply that `.click()` to open the file chooser dialog does not work on all browsers. I'm not aware of any workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Not supported in Gecko yet:

```
Gecko 2.0 note(Firefox 4) 

Starting in Gecko 2.0 , calling the click() method on an <input> element of 
type file opens the file picker and lets the user select files.
```

from https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/input#File_inputs